# How to do drag and drop a page from the application to the desktop/ Explorer

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

How to do drag and drop a page from the application to the desktop/ Explorer in win32. My application is document management system.

Please help me how to get the handle of the desktop/explorer window or any other window outside of the application.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement drag & drop in your application? If so, you don't need to get the handle of the desktop or any other window for that.

Comment: So what i need for doing drag and drop?   Jonathan Potter

Comment: What do you mean with "Drag a page"? What data is to be dragged and dropped. Dragging and dropping data means to define what you want to drag and requires that the target is able top accept this data.

Comment: Raymond Chen's Excellent series on Drag & Drop: [What a Drag](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/tags/what+a+drag/)

Comment: Also MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96826a87.aspx